# Insert Modal input value into form/table before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys I need help to insert the input values that is inside the Modal(which is pulled from database using autocomplete) into the tables for preview before submitting the form.

Here is the modal image -> and the data insertion should happen after clicking the "Add Owner" button,
[image]

here is table image -> which will have row added everytime a new owner is added.

[image]

Below is my JS code,

```
large.on('click', '.add-modal-owner', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();

            //clear all data upon close/save
            $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
                $("input").val("");
                $('[name=optionsRadios4]',form).each(function(){
                    $(this).prop('checked',false).uniform('refresh');
                });
                $('#student_photo').attr('src', '');
                $("[name=matrik_number]").select2("val", "");

                $("tbody").data( $("[name=student_name]").data() );

                var student_data = {"id":matrik_number.val(),"name":$("[name=student_name]").val(),"ic":$("[name=student_ic]").val(),
                                    "birthplace":$("[name=student_birthplace]").val(),"faculty":$("[name=faculty_name]").val(),
                                    "phone":$("[name=student_phoneno]").val(),"email":$("[name=student_emailadd]").val()};
                var row = $("<tr></tr>").data(student_data);
```

(I got lost at looping the tables while trying to insert the data too using .data() method. THe above only have the reset values code as the working code. I need help with the last 6 lines though.

Below is my HTML code(for Modal)

```
<div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                            aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Owner</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body" id="form">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-10 center-block">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Matrik No. <span
                                                        class="required"> * </span></label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                                        <input name="matrik_number" class="form-control select2" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3"></label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                                        <img name="student_photo" id="student_photo" alt=""
                                                            class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Name</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_name" id="student_name" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                            readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">IC Number</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_ic" id="student_ic" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                            readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Birth Place</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_birthplace" id="student_birthplace" type="text"
                                                            class="form-control" readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Faculty</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="faculty_name" id="faculty_name" type="text"
                                                            class="form-control" readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Study Year</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_studyyear" id="student_studyyear" type="text"
                                                            class="form-control" readonly>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Phone No.</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_phoneno" id="student_phone" maxlength="11" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" type="text"
                                                            class="form-control">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">E-Mail</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input name="student_emailadd" id="student_email" type="text" maxlength="50"
                                                            class="form-control">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Year Start
                                                        Business</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <div class="radio-list">
                                                            <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio"
                                                                name="optionsRadios4" value="option1" /> 1
                                                            </label> <label class="radio-inline"> <input
                                                                type="radio" name="optionsRadios4" value="option2" />
                                                                2
                                                            </label> </label> <label class="radio-inline"> <input
                                                                type="radio" name="optionsRadios4" value="option3" />
                                                                3
                                                            </label> <label class="radio-inline"> <input
                                                                type="radio" name="optionsRadios4" value="option4" />
                                                                4
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn dark btn-outline"
                                            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <a class="btn green add-modal-owner" data-dismiss="modal">Add Owner</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Based on this example -> http://jsfiddle.net/Qw2VY/2/

Below is my code, hope it will help someone.

```
large.on('click', '.add-modal-owner', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if(matrik_number != ''){
            //insert modal data to tables/forms
                $('tbody',tab_owner).append(                
                        $("<tr>\n" +
                        "<td>" + $('[name=matrik_number]').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td>" + $('#student_name').val()+ "</td>\n" +
                        "<td>" + $('#student_ic').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td>" + $('#student_birthplace').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td>" + $('#faculty_name').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td>" + $('#student_phone').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td>" + $('#student_email').val() + "</td>\n" +
                        "<td width='3%'><a class='btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm purple edit-workers pull-right'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i>Edit</a></td>" +
                        "<td width='3%'><a class='btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm red del-owner pull-right'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i>Remove</a></td>" +
                        "</tr>\n")
                        );

                //clear all data upon close/save
                $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
                    $("input").val("");
                    $('[name=optionsRadios4]',form).each(function(){
                        $(this).prop('checked',false).uniform('refresh');
                    });
                    $('#student_photo').attr('src', '');
                    $("[name=matrik_number]").select2("val", "");
                });

            };
        });
```